# spring boot Neo4j⚡️RX dto projection with relationship not working

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-rest, spring-data-neo4j, reactive

I am trying to use DTO projection, to get only selected relation by the DTO to optimize Neo4j query.

It works fine with normal fields but when I try to get insight relationship with the projected fields, it returns null.

This is my Node entity

```
@Node("Subscription")
data class Subscription(
        @Id
        val id: UUID,
        @Relationship(type = "TO_PLAN", direction = OUTGOING)
        val plan: SubscriptionPlan?,
        @Relationship(type = "HAS_INVOICE", direction = OUTGOING)
        val invoice: Invoice?,
        @Relationship(type = "HAS_INSIGHT", direction = OUTGOING)
        val insight: Map<Insight, SubscriptionInsightsRelationship>,
        val status: SubscriptionStatuses,
        val isAutoRenewal: Boolean,
        val insightsLastChange: LocalDateTime?,
        @CreatedDate
        val createdDate: LocalDateTime?,
        @LastModifiedDate
        val lastModifiedDate: LocalDateTime?
)
```

> The Map is how to set rich relationship in Neo4j⚡️RX

This is my projection DTO

```
data class RetrieveSubscriptionDto(
        val id: UUID,
        val insight: Map<Insight, SubscriptionInsightsRelationship>?,
        val status: SubscriptionStatuses,
        val lastModifiedDate: LocalDateTime?
)
```

This is the repository

```
interface SubscriptionRepository : ReactiveNeo4jRepository<Subscription, UUID> {
    fun findAllByIdIsNotNull(): Flux<RetrieveSubscriptionDto>
}
```

The returned value with this projection is

```
   {
        "id": "d3a816e5-d0be-4721-b34d-346b011b9757",
        "insight": null,
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "lastModifiedDate": "2020-10-18T01:29:40.37691"
    }
```

Comment: need some more info on - what is the query used?
how does your repository looks?

Comment: @Lucia I edited the post regarding the repository, I am trying to use DTO projection, to get only selected relation by the DTO to optimize Neo4j query.